# Cloudera - dynamic Resource Pool for user

Tags: dynamic, resources, scheduler, cloudera

I am running a Cloudera Cluster on Yarn with the version 5.8.2. The 
scheduler of the Resource manager is running as Fair scheduler.
The dynamic resource Pool setting for YARN is active. The pools are 
generated under root.users..

What I want is to increase the resources for a specific user. So I changed 
the weight in the dynamic resource configuration for this user from "1" to 
"3".

Assume I have three users USER1 to USER3 and have the follwing wheigting.
USER1 is 3, USER2 is 1, USER3 is 1.

Am I right that USER3 is able to get three times more Cluster resources than
USER2 and USER3 ?

If all Users running jobs on the cluster at the same time, USER3 gets "60" 
percent of root resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined any restriction, user3 gets 60% of cluster resource.
You can know more about fair scheduler in [cloudera blog](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/)